# PHPFOX : The feature or section you are attempting to use is not permitted with your membership level

Tags: feed, usergroups, phpfox

If you have PHPFOX 3.7.7(build 2) and you get this problem, Its a bug that messes completely the system, stops the feeds for all members, and a quick fix is to erase (delete) last few postings until problem gets fixed. Nobody is able to view any pages (only admins, so an admin has to erase the last postings to get site up and going), just the menu is available to users and guests and the error msg **"The feature or section you are attempting to use is not permitted with your membership level"**

This bug happens, right after a user comments a link or share a video on a  group or fanpages wall only. Its a feed issue permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix is simple, but hard to find. Spent days looking for it, thats why I share it with you.

```
// Open file "module/link/include/service/callback.class.php", line 92, replace this line:
$aNewUser = Phpfox::getService('user')->getForEdit($aPage['page_user_id']);

// With this line:
$aNewUser = Phpfox::getService('user')->getUser($aPage['page_user_id']);
```

It worked for me, Im a happy camper now...
Thanks to this site that was shared on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/usQvkDxm